Ошибка в DateFormat. не смотря на то что все зависимости подключены
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:goschool/constants.dart';
import 'package:goschool/widgets/header.dart';
import 'package:goschool/widgets/recent_alerts.dart';
import 'package:goschool/widgets/recents_homeworks.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget> [
        Header(),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(color: kTextColor),
            cursorColor: kTextColor,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              filled: true,
              hintText: "Search",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: kTextColor),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.search, color: kTextColor, 
                size: 26),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

SizedBox(height: 30),
Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
topRight: Radius.circular(50),
),
),
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
children:  [
Text(
"Recent Alerts",
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
fontSize: 20,
fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
),
),
SizedBox(height: 30),
RecentsAlerts(),
Center(
child: Text(
"view all",
style: TextStyle(
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
fontSize: 15,
),
),
),
    SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text("Recent HomeWork",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color:Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
                    RecentsHomeworks(),
                    Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "view all", 
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                        ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
          ],),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. Приглашаем вас ознакомиться со справкой, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Не совсем понял, как заголовок относится к коду, который вызывает ошибку.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Получение текущей даты:
DateTime _date = DateTime.now();

Добавите в место, где хотите вывести дату:
Text(DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(_date)),

